# Get current column number in Excel (non-programmatically)

Tags: excel-2010

All I want to do, is to be able to see my column headings a numbers instead of the lettering scheme that excel uses.

Every Google search returns some script-based answer. Isn't there a setting for this?

Also, if I don't want to convert all the columns to numbers, but only want to see the current column's number (that I am in), how can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean something like the [R1C1](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T008803_Understanding_R1C1_References.html) reference style?

Answer (score 0):

Click any cell in the worksheet and enter the formula:

```
=Column()
```

The formula will display the column **as a number**.